# Sublime 3 text - automatically build system when saving a file

Tags: node.js, npm, save, sublimetext3, system

How to disable auto-build, when I am trying to save a file in sublime3?
There's no shortcut problem. I checked the Tool-Build and the shortcut for this is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. The shortcut for saving files is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. But it always automatically builds a system when I want to save any files in sublime.

The message said:

> npm install.

I tried to remove npm and node by using `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}`
. These two are removed because I can't find anything from terminal by checking `node -v` and `npm -v`. However, when I try to save file in sublime3 again, it still runs the npm install, even though it said can't find path this time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! Click **sublime text-preference-package setting- npminstall-setting user-{"install_on_save": false}-save it**.

I checked my sublime3, it's not a shortcut problem because shortcut for build is still <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and the shortcut for save file is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

I removed the npm and node from terminal but when it still shows npm saving when I want to save a file. 
So I checked the sublime again and found npminstall package in preference. Now i have to reinstall node and npm.